# mysql get results from two tables using a link table

Tags: php, mysql

Can you please guys help how to perform the right query to have an "output" as shown on the image below.
I really appreciate it guys if you could help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Everything seems fine, what have you tried ?

Comment: You already have your output in your image, so you have no problem ;) Seriously, you should read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and show evidence of what you've actually tried (e.g. code). This is not a code writing service where people enter problems and solutions magically pop into existence. Whoever up-voted this question should seriously read the how to ask page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would do a JOIN like this:

```
SELECT rt.room_name AS Room, at.amenities_name AS Amenities FROM
link_table AS lt JOIN room_table AS rt ON lt.room_id = rt.room_id
JOIN amenities_table AS at ON lt.amenities_id = at.amenities_id;
```

to get a result like this:

```
Room       Amenities
--------------------
Room 101   WIFI
Room 101   A/C
...        ...
Room 102   A/C
...        ...
```